# Removing (NOT Deleting) A File/Upload From Jupyter Notebooks Home Page

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I realize this is probably super simple but I've been googling it endlessly with no luck. I want to remove a file from the home page/dashboard that opens when I launch Jupyter Notebooks. The only option I can find is the Delete button (red trashcan), but this removes the file from the hard drive as well. I don't want to delete it from my computer, I just want to get it off the Jupyter dashboard. The only descriptions I can find in the documentation are for deleting files entirely, which doesn't help if you're just looking to decluter your main dashboard without actually deleting the file from your hard drive.

Thanks!

[Jupyter Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zkvm.jpg)

I've tried reading through Jypter's documentation, as well as googling and searching through this and other sites. I have not found a description of how to accomplish this specific task.

Comment: Looks like your notebook is opening in your home directory (see the `/` at the top).  So it's showing everything in that directory, same as if you used file brower or `dir` command.  You might want to open it in a different directory, one with just the desired (working) files.  The simplest way is to just `cd` to that directory, and run `jupyter notebook` from there.  You can also specify the directory in the command line, or in a configuration file.

Comment: You could also use the `move` button to move that file to some other directory.  Or while in the dashboard, you can change the current directory.  The dashboard gives you a lot of the same functionality as the Windows FileExplorer.